# Webdriver grabbing text via executeScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium WebdriverJS for node.js

the docs say that when using `executeScript();`, if the script has a return statement then

> For a HTML element, the value will resolve to a WebElement

So I am trying to grab an elementusing this method to explore how it works, but I cannot get the text from the webElement.

I've tried grabbing text from google.com in the following ways:

Normal way using webdriver API:

```
var glink = '#gbw > div > div > div.gb_7d.gb_R.gb_hg.gb_9f > div:nth-child(1) > a';

find(glink).getText().then(function(t){
    console.log(t);
})
```

This works as intended. But the following don't work:

```
var gett = function(){
    return driver.executeScript("return document.querySelectorAll('#gbw > div > div > div.gb_7d.gb_R.gb_hg.gb_9f > div:nth-child(1) > a')").then(function(result){
        result.getText().then(function(txt){
            console.log(txt)
        })
    });
}

var gett2 = function(){
    return driver.executeScript("return document.querySelectorAll('#gbw > div > div > div.gb_7d.gb_R.gb_hg.gb_9f > div:nth-child(1) > a')").getText().then(function(txt){
        console.log(txt)
    })
};

var gett3 = function(){
    return driver.executeScript("return document.querySelectorAll('#gbw > div > div > div.gb_7d.gb_R.gb_hg.gb_9f > div:nth-child(1) > a')", function(result){
        return result.getText().then(function(t){
            console.log(t);
        });
    });
};
```

None of these work when called. The first two throw a `TypeError: result.getText is not a function`, while the last one throws no error, but nothing happens and the browser quits successfully when calling `driver.quit()`.

Why don't these work? And how can I grab a webelemernt using `executeScript`?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but this might help someone else.  I have been learning Selenium with mocha recently and have struggled mightily with the resolution of promises.  I believe in this case you just need one more step to return the values you expect, the main issue is trying to call getText() on the full node of values, rather than the individual element.  You have to first iterate over the individual elements in the node before applying getText().  Try this, something similar worked for me.

```
    var gett = function() {
  return driver
    .executeScript(
      "return document.querySelectorAll('#gbw > div > div > div.gb_7d.gb_R.gb_hg.gb_9f > div:nth-child(1) > a')"
    )
    .then(function(results) {
      results.forEach(function(result) {
        result.getText().then(function(txt) {
          console.log(txt);
        });
      });
    });
};
```